# Matchmaking in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have implemented a cloud function for firebase that takes care of matchmaking.
It works like that: if a player looks for a game, my function first checks if there are any open games(another user looking for a game) if there is such a game, I update the game by saying it's a closed game. if no open game has been found, I create a new open game.
with this implementation I have the following question: let's assume player A created an open game and now Player B and Player C are looking for a game at the same time. How can I avoid that both of them getting assigned to player A open Game. So basically I only want ONE of them assigned.

EDIT:

I save my games in firestore and i have a property called player2 which is set to -1 if there is no player2 yet.
my implementation looks like this:

```js
exports.findGame = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    //get game with no player2
    const gameWithoutPlayer2 = await admin.
        firestore()
        .collection('games')
        .where("player2", "==", "-1")
        .limit(1)
        .get();


    //check if a game without player2 exist
    if (gameWithoutPlayer2.docs[0] == null) {
        //no game found => create new one
        await createNewGame(context.auth.uid);
    } else {
        //game found => we are player2
        //get name of player:
        const player2Result = await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(context.auth.uid).get();
        await admin.firestore().collection('games').doc(gameWithoutPlayer2.docs[0].id).update({ player2: context.auth.uid, player2Name: player2Result.data().Username });     
    }
})
```

Comment: You need to provide a bit more information :) It's not clear how your matches are stored. Are you using firestore, realtime db or something else? how is your cloud function triggered?

Comment: It sounds like you have an implementation that is not working how you want it to work. On Stack Overflow it is much more likely that folks can help if you show the actual code that reproduces the problem. Have a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn more about such a minimal repro.

Comment: @TroelsLenda i edited my question :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Firestore Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) (at least for the matchmaking part in the waiting room) and also taking a look into [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions), which will ensure that no one has created or joined a game while we are attempting to do it via atomic operations.

I have found [here](https://github.com/zillesc/Matchmaker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ninja/zilles/matchmaker/MainActivity.java) an implementation on Java using Firestore Realtime Database and Transactions that could be useful to you.